# htaccess cannot read cookies in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, firefox, cookies

I have the following code in .htaccess file that is not working in Firefox 25. It's works ok with Chrome, IE, Safari.

```
Header unset Cache-Control
Header append Cache-Control "no-cache, must-revalidate"
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*userloggedin.*$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} userloggedin=x
RewriteRule .* http://www.bostonneca.org/redir.php
```

I used the code to check if a cookie is set. If is not set, then I redirect the user to the login page. After log in, the user can access the folder.

```
setcookie('userloggedin', 'ok', time() + 60 * 60 * 5);
```

I guess it's a server issue because I cannot remove cookies with setcookie('userloggedin', '', time() - 1);
To avoid this issue, on the logout I write a cookie

```
setcookie('userloggedin', 'x', time() + 60 * 60 * 5);
```

Please help!

Thanks,
Adrian

Comment: Have you had a look into `RewriteLog` output and what headers go through FireBug or console ? You can handle all cookie stuff without rewrite anyways.

Comment: In Firebug, the cookie is set(please see the screenshots) http://varusoft.com/_ps/20131206-610-276kb.jpg
 and  
http://varusoft.com/_ps/20131206-h33-310kb.jpg

Somehow, the cookies aren't visible in htaccess in combination with Firefox.

Comment: I don't have access to see RewriteLog ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging help:

**FireBug** / **Console** - look into the headers if the cookie gets set and sent

**RewriteLog** - Find missconfiguration of the Rewrite

enable by:

```
RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

(suggested is level 3 for debugging)

See also this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/499246/how-do-i-make-rewritecond-http-cookie-match-a-cookie-value-exactly

As an alternative, you can test the cookie with PHP in your index.php or whatever file you are loading or, you can redirect every request to `redir.php` and check the cookie in this file.

Comment: Thank you for the time spent to help me. I appreciate it. The RewriteLog didn't worked on the server(internal server error) so I changed the code to display the private content through php.